# Как создать в программе txt

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, у меня такой вопрос, как создать в программе текстовый файл, который после запуска появится в той директории в которой, открыл эту программу пользователь, ну или чтобы он создавался на рабочем столе ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Создаём файл по относительному пути (он создастся в папке с проектом):

```
File file = new File("file.txt"); 
file.createNewFile();
```

Создаём файл по абсолютному пути:

```
File file = new File("/path/to/file/file.txt"); 
file.createNewFile();
```

Например, создадим файл на рабочем столе в Mac OS:

```
File file = new File("/Users/UserName/Desktop/file.txt");
file.createNewFile();
```

Тогда файл `file.txt` будет создан на рабочем столе у пользователя `UserName`.

Важно: файл создастся только в том случае, если такого файла ещё нет и у программы будет достаточно на это прав.

---

Более сложный пример:

```
// путь до файла 'text.txt' в папке 'files' внутри папки проекта
String pathToFile = "files/text.txt";
File file = new File(pathToFile);

boolean isFileExists = file.exists(); // проверяем, есть ли уже такой файл
boolean fileCreated = false;

if (!isFileExists) {
    fileCreated = file.createNewFile(); // если файл создастся, то будет true
}

System.out.println("Is file created? " + fileCreated); // выводим результат
```

Comment: я бы еще проверил нет ли уже файла в директории, в вообще конечно это легко [гуглится](https://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20java&lr=213&clid=2186621).

Comment: @Dejsving да, естественно, я привёл лишь самый примитивный пример и ответил на вопрос. Проверки, создался ли файл, нет ли его уже в директории, и так далее - это уже отдельно :)

Comment: Если файл уже создан, по идее по новой он не создастся, да?

Comment: @НечаевИлья дополнил ответ.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin спасибо, увидел.

Answer (score 4):

Из [официальной документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html#creating):

```
Path file = Paths.get("file.txt");
try {
    // Create the empty file with default permissions, etc.
    Files.createFile(file);
} catch (FileAlreadyExistsException x) {
    System.err.format("file named %s already exists%n", file);
} catch (IOException x) {
    // Some other sort of failure, such as permissions.
    System.err.format("createFile error: %s%n", x);
}
```